# Set keyboard on screen

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, uitextview

Is there any way to set the keyboard to be on screen upon loading of the view aside from using

```
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

I need this because i want the user to see the placeholder text even if the keyboard is already fixed in the screen.

Comment: How are you showing placeholder text for textView?

Comment: I set the default text to be something like `@"Enter your text here"` and then remove it when the user starts typing by calling `- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView`

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [Super viewDidLoad];
     textView = [ [UITextview alloc]initwithFrame:frame];// Customise TextView
     textview.text = @"Enter your text here";
     [textview becomeFirstResponder];
     [self.view addSubview:textview];
}
```

This may help you

Answer (score 1):

According to what you commented, Don't hide the placeholder text when the textView just begins editing. Instead, you should use the delegate method `shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` of `UITextView` to calculate the length of textView's text and if it is zero, show your placeholder string, otherwise not.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
       NSString* txt = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
       if([txt length] == 0)
       // Show your place holder text
       else   
       // Hide your place holder text
}
```

Comment: I think this is not a good idea since I am using `[textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];` The code you gave will cause crash on my app. and also  i'll type a text, it will append the placeholder to the text that I just typed.

Comment: If you are appending to your original placeholder text, you can check for the original placeholder's length instead of zero. Besides, your comment said something like this "I set the default text to be something like @"Enter your text here" and then remove it when the user starts typing....." So basically I answered to that. Remember the word Remove :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I really appreciate your help. but i ended up using a subclass of a `UITextView` to have a placeholder property. :)